# Margins outside Grid layout

Tags: css, layout, grid, margins

I have some problems to add a margin to my grid layout.
I can't insert margins to the body or my .container that is taking the whole viewport.
When the page gets scrollable... the vertical scrollbar forces also a horizontal scrollbar.

```
.container {
    height:100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr  auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "content"
        "footer"
    ;   
}
```

Comment: Show the html code also

Comment: You can also try box-sizing: border-box, this makes any padding or borders not impact the overall width

Comment: Found the culprit....
i had to initialize owlcarousel with window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Use "*box-sizing: border-box*"

```
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "content"
        "footer"
    ;
}
```